# Where to find numerical simulations for motion of particles in Schwarzschild geometry?

Tags: general-relativity, computational-physics

I have written a simulator of particle motion in the Schwarzschild geometry and I would like to compare it to other peoples' results. Where can I find a paper where they have done numerical simulations of this, and where plots of the motion are given?

I am numerically solving

$u''(\phi)+u(\phi)=\frac{1}{2 h^2}+\frac{3 u(\phi)^2}{2}$

where $u=1/r$.

(All the papers I come across are entirely theoretical, no plots of motion with initial conditions are given).

Comment: If you like Mathematica notebooks for your computation and plotting, you might try http://library.wolfram.com/infocenter/MathSource/5258/

Answer (score 0):

The [black hole perturbation toolkit](https://github.com/BlackHolePerturbationToolkit/) is a collection of tools involved in calculating things around black holes. It contains a package ([KerrGeodesics](https://github.com/BlackHolePerturbationToolkit/KerrGeodesics)) for solving (bound) geodesics in Kerr spacetime. Schwarzschild is just a special case. The (analytic!) solutions used in that package are based on this paper by Fujita&Hikida: [0906.1420v2](https://arxiv.org/abs/0906.1420v2)

Comment: This looks really good, I've downloaded it, but it's not clear to me how to use it. How do we know, for example, what the function `KerrGeoOrbits` wants as inputs? The documentation has some examples but they just put in some numbers without specifying what they mean. (Will accept answer once I get it to work out)

Comment: In particular, we have `KerrGeoOrbits[a,p,e,x]`. I think `a` is angular momentum per unit mass, what about p,e,x ?

Comment: All inputs are dimensionless numbers (or equivalently expressed in units where G=c=M=1). `a` is the spin angular momentum of the Kerr black hole per unit mass squared. `p` is the semi-latus rectum of the orbit divided by the mass of the central black hole, 'e' is the eccentricity of the orbit, and `x` relates to the inclination of the orbit. For your purposes `a=0` and `x=1`.

Answer (score 0):

As mmeent pointed out you can use the [Black Hole Perturbation Toolkit](http://bhptoolkit.org/), [KerrGeodesics](http://bhptoolkit.org/KerrGeodesics/) Mathematica package to find the solutions for generic bound timelike orbits around a black hole.

To make the inputs clearer I've added an 'Orbital Parametrization' section to the [KerrGeodesics webpage](http://bhptoolkit.org/KerrGeodesics/). I've also added the the same description to the tutorial in the documentation. The orbital parameterization is described in, e.g., Sec. II of  [arXiv:gr-qc/0509101](https://arxiv.org/abs/gr-qc/0509101).